# online training with sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM?

Tags: python, bigdata, scikit-learn

I was wondering if we could play with the fit() method sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM to be able to do online training.

I understand that RBM takes minibatches as inputs however, I don't have all the training data loaded:

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

//X_train,Y_train big ndarrays with 25000 rows and 50000 columns and not necessarily      sparse: they are not loaded yet. They can only be accessed one minibatch at a time (a minibatch in my definition is a matrix with 100 rows and 50000 columns))

```
batchSize=100
nIterations=25000/100
idx1=0
idx2=batchSize
for i in range(nIterations):

    rbm = BernoulliRBM(batch_size=100,random_state=0, verbose=True)
    rbm.fit(X_train[idx1:idx2], learning_rate=0.1, n_components=2, n_iter=10,
    random_state=None, verbose=False)
    idx1=idx1+batchSize
    idx2=idx2+batchSize
```

//after all training is done:

```
idx1=0
idx2=batchSize
for i in range(nIterations):

rbm.transform(X_train[idx1:idx2])
idx1=idx1+batchSize
idx2=idx2+batchSize
```

My general Knowledge of datascience and programming isn't that great. I've been stuck on this for a couple of weeks and was wondering if I could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The public API for incremental learning is not there yet for the `BernoulliRBM` class. There is an open [issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2400).